# Conjugation of verb in sentence adverbial clause and subjunctive

Tags: gramática, subjuntivo

> Ellos lo hacen de manera que no (haber) errores.

Why is this haya and not hay? The main clause is in the indicative.

Comment: "Ellos lo hacen de manera que no hay errores" would be correct too, I think.

Answer (score 1):

When exist a possibility you use the *subjuntivo*.

When it is true or if you have the possibility implicit, you do not use the *subjuntivo*.

`ellos lo hacen de manera que no haya errores, tienen un buen departamento de control de calidad.`

`ellos lo hiceron de manera que no haya errores, vamos a probarlo.`

`ello lo hicieron de manera que no hay errores, estoy sano y salvo.`

The last can be said in a better way, but works.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'm not an expert in grammar.

But my idea is that subjuntive in clauses introduced by **que** are used when the second verb denotes an action related to the subject of the first one, but the first person is not the actual subject. The usual cases are when the first verb denotes *emotion*, but also *responsibility*, *intention* or similar things:

> Me alegro de que no haya errores.
>
> Intenta que no haya errores.
>
> Ellos lo hacen de manera que no haya errores.

But:

> He visto que no hay errores.

The subjuntive will also be used when the first verb is impersonal:

> Es importante que no haya errores.
>
> No importa que no haya errores.

It is worth noting that similar phrases using **si** instead of **que** will not usually have the subjuntive:

> No importa si no hay errores.
>
> Me enfadaré si hay errores.

Comment: I don't think it has nothing to do with the first person, and "haya" isn't even first person on that sentence. First and Third person are equal, but it doesn't mean the sentence uses the first person. Compare: "Espero que yo no cometa errores" vs "Espero que tú no cometas errores" vs "Espero que Paco no cometa errores". First, Second and Third persons respectively.

Comment: @Flamma: When I say _first person_ I mean the subject of the first verb. A bad choice of words, it seems.

Comment: Oh, I see. Still, I'm not sure the answer is correct anyway. In "Espero que yo no haya cometido errores", both phrases in the sentence have the same subject, and the verb is still on subjunctive form.

Comment: @Flamma: Well, I'm not sure either. But my idea is kind of sencences are one use of the subjuntube, but by no means the only one. Desires and hypothesis are still subjuntive, even if they do not fit answer. Compare "creo que he cometido errores" vs "no creo que haya cometido errores".

Answer (score 0):

Subjunctive here would be the most common choice, because it's they are doing things *such that*, or *with the intended goal of* (there is no way to know that will be the actual result of their action).  Compare to "lo hicieron para que no hubiese errores".

However, as Helmut points out, when what comes in the subordinate clause is not the goal, but rather the result, then indicative is the correct choice.  Compare to "lo hicieron de una manera paricular, así que no hay errores".

Answer (score 0):

The "idiomatic" English translation is, "They do it this way so there won't be errors."

But a more accurate translation is, "They do it this way so there *should not be* errors" (subjunctive). The Spanish form, *haya* conveys this sense, the English does not.